# einschränken vs beschränken vs eingrenzen vs begrenzen vs einengen

Tags: synonym

What is the difference between these verbs which express "to restrict", "to limit" in German: einschränken, beschränken, eingrenzen, begrenzen, einengen? My conclusions so far:

- einschränken= "to restrict" = "to reduce".
  Caused deliberately by sb. or his actions (eg. decree), a government, a company, etc
- beschränken = "to limit" = "to set a limit (often a point) for sth., beyond which there will be a penalty or undesirable consequences". Caused deliberately or by the inherent nature of things (eg rain, land, water)
- as setting a limit implicitly defines a restriction, the 2 verbs may be used interchangeably in most contexts. In some contexts, one of them is used more often (eg "to limit"/"beschränken" is more common with speed limits, "to restrict"/"einschränken" with freedom and rights)
- einengen = to restrict movement or space (concrete meaning), to reduce the scope (= narrow down), to restrict (abstract meaning)
- begrenzen = to limit/restrict, to border
- eingrenzen = to enclose, to reduce the number of possibilities or the scope of sth. ( = to narrow down)

Is that right? Here are some examples and my corresponding guesses:

- The government limited / restricted the max speed in all highways to 100 km/h =
  Die Regierung hat die Höchstgeschwindigkeit auf allen Schnellstraßen auf 100 km/h begrenzt / beschränkt.
- We have limited / restricted our stay to one week = Wir haben unseren Aufenthalt auf eine Woche begrenzt / beschränkt.
- Dictators always restrict people's rights. = Diktatoren begrenzen / grenzen /engen / schränken immer die Rechte der Menschen (ein).
- The new decree restricted freedom of speech. =
  Das neue Dekret hat die Redefreiheit begrenzt / eingegrenzt / eingeengt / eingeschränkt.
- The new jacket restricted him. (it is very tight) = Die neue Jacke hat ihn etwas eingeengt.
- We limited / restricted our consumption of milk to 5 liters per week. = Wir haben unseren Verbrauch auf 5 Liter pro Woche begrenzt / beschränkt.
- This poor soil limits what can be planted here. = Dieser schlechte Boden begrenzt / grenzt / engt / beschränkt / schränkt (ein), was hier gepflanzt werden kann.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your so-called "guesses" are beautiful. :-) Yet, let me give you some hints here and there to make them completely idiomatic.

*Die Regierung hat die Höchstgeschwindigkeit auf allen Schnellstraßen auf 100 km/h begrenzt / beschränkt.* - **PERFECT**

*Wir haben unseren Aufenthalt auf eine Woche begrenzt / beschränkt.* - I'd prefer *beschränken* to *begrenzen*, but that's rather a matter of personal taste.

*Diktatoren begrenzen / grenzen /engen / schränken immer die Rechte der Menschen (ein).* - *begrenzen* isn't possible here, whereas *einschränken* would be my preference. *beschneiden* would also be fine here.

*Das neue Dekret hat die Redefreiheit begrenzt / eingegrenzt / eingeengt / eingeschränkt.* - *einschränken* is perfect, *einengen* might be ok, the other two seem unidiomatic to me.

*Die neue Jacke hat ihn etwas eingeengt.* - Um ... sounds a bit emphatic in my ears. I'd say: *Die neue Jacke war ihm zu eng. Er konnte sich kaum noch bewegen.* or *Die Jacke war zu eng und hat seine Bewegungsfreiheit eingeschränkt.*

*Wir haben unseren (? Verbrauch ? ->) Milchkonsum auf 5 Liter pro Woche begrenzt / beschränkt.* - Here again rather *beschränken* than *begrenzen*. As the intake was higher before, I'd suggest *reduzieren*.

*Dieser schlechte Boden begrenzt / grenzt / engt / beschränkt / schränkt (ein), was hier gepflanzt werden kann.* - Hmmm ... das klingt für mich sehr konstruiert. ;-) Idomatisch wäre z.B. *Der schlechte Boden lässt nur wenige Arten zu. / ... lässt nur die Pflanzung weniger Arten zu.*

Seems like *begrenzen* doesn't stand much chances for me :-))

Comment: From DWDS examples of"begrenzen", it seems to me that it's used in its conjugated form only as "to limit" (= set a maximum point, draw a boundary) indeed, eg Geschwindigkeit, Redezeit, Aufnahmealter begrenzen. Nevertheless, it is also used in past participle with a wider meaning of restriction, eg  begrenzter Wettbewerb, Möglichkeiten, Wirkung, Horizon.

Answer (score -3):

- *einschränken*, related to *Schrank* "closet" and in the same way relates to *to close-in*, *close-off*
- *beschränken* relates further to "Schranke" (En. "..."?), to *set up borde posts*, now fig. of figurative *areas*, *ideas*
- The way you describe it, my above notions might be the other way around, sure.
- *einengen* "constrict", much narrower meaning. A narrow is tightend. Otherwise its often encroaching on *bedrängen*. Comparing *to shrink*, there might be a notable parallel to *-schränken*, as narrow passes are notoriously subject to fencing and taxation.
- Grenze, middle ages Latin, same ideas as for *-schränken*, but a later development